# How do I get the cursor location in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Is there a simple way to get the x,y cursor location at any point with OpenGL without using glutPassiveMotionFunc() to track it? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. OpenGL is not meant to give you such information. If you are using Windows, you can use `GetCursorPos`.

But I would suggest you to track it since it makes it cross platform. You will also need to use `glutMotionFunc` to track mouse position when a mouse button is pushed.